# Mysql how to change variable

Tags: mysql

my problem is this:

```
$channeldb = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM channels AS ch
            LEFT JOIN groups AS gr 
            ON gr.code = ch.code
            ". $searchdb ." LIMIT 100");
while($channel = mysql_fetch_assoc($channeldb))
...
```

variable $cannel[id] is from table groups but i need from channels

like this:

```
$ch-id = ch.id;
```

but how :)

Thank you for helping

Comment: Easy answer. Do not use select *....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly select the columns that you want.  For instance:

```
SELECT ch.id
FROM channels ch LEFT JOIN
     groups gr 
     ON gr.code = ch.code;
```

For application code, you should not be using `SELECT *` for (at least) four reasons:

- If the underlying tables change, that can affect your code (and this is hard to debug).
- If tables have the same columns, you get confusion.
- Bringing back extra, unused columns is just a waste of bandwidth (and hence time).
- Your code should be quite clear about the data it is using.

If you need both ids, then alias them:

```
SELECT ch.id as channel_id, gr.id s group_id
FROM channels ch LEFT JOIN
     groups gr 
     ON gr.code = ch.code;
```

Also, if you have a unique id in each table, it should probably be used for the `JOIN`, rather than `code`.

Answer (score 0):

Use select id from channels, then the query will return the id from channels